# Вращение с помощью кватернионов JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Здравствуйте! Рисую 3D-объект с помощью OpenGl на java. Возникла необходимость перемещать и вращать этот объект вокруг своих осей. Пользовался стандартным вариантом для вращения:

```
gl.glRotatef(angleRotateX, 1f, 0f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef(angleRotateY, 0f, 1f, 0f);
gl.glRotatef(angleRotateZ, 0f, 0f, 1f);
```

Но, на большое удивление, ожидаемо работает только вращение вокруг Z. Вращение вокруг остальных осей происходит вокруг глобальной системы координат.

Попытался использовать кватернионы:

```
Quaternion xQ = new Quaternion((float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleRotateX) / 2f), 0f, 0f, (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleRotateX) / 2f));
Quaternion yQ = new Quaternion(0f, (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleRotateY) / 2f), 0f, (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleRotateY) / 2f));
Quaternion zQ = new Quaternion(0f, 0f, (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleRotateZ) / 2f), (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleRotateZ) / 2f));

xQ.normalize();
yQ.normalize();
zQ.normalize();

float[] xM = new  float[3];
float[] yM = new  float[3];
float[] zM = new  float[3];
Quaternion rQ = xQ.mult(yQ).mult(zQ);
rQ.toAxes(xM, yM, zM, new float[16]);

gl.glRotatef(angleRotateX, xM[0], xM[1], xM[2]);
gl.glRotatef(angleRotateY, yM[0], yM[1], yM[2]);
gl.glRotatef(angleRotateZ, zM[0], zM[1], zM[2]);
```

Результат, к сожалению, остался точно таким же. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте привести пример поворота по **двум** углам. Ожидание и реальность. Пока что ничего кроме "у вас не те углы" сказать нельзя.